# How to setup production ubuntu server with django, gunicorn, nginx and celery?

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, rabbitmq, celery

I need to setup production server on ubuntu precise, I read lot of howtos and put bits and pieces together.Below I will post (hopefully) all related configs. But to point you where to look first I list all the problems:

1. when I don't manually type https:// I got incorrect redirect in firefox
2. when I type https:// I got to admin login but can't login with correct username/pass and I don't know how to debug it because I can't find any log containing what runserver outputs to console(i tried file logger in settings.py but log stays empty)
3. my app runs under subdomain.domain.com -should I put subdomain.domain.com or just domain.com in settings.py DOMAIN= ?
4. what to chenge to make gunicorn work with self signed certificate as in commented line in`gunicorn.conf`?
5. Why `/var/log/upstart/celercam.log` is full of `Error in timer: TransactionManagementError("This code isn't under transaction management",)`

---

`pip freeze`:

```
Django==1.5.4
MySQL-python==1.2.4
PIL==1.1.7
Pillow==2.2.1
PyYAML==3.10
South==0.8.4
amqp==1.3.3
anyjson==0.3.3
argparse==1.2.1
billiard==3.3.0.8
celery==3.1.5
django-celery==3.1.1
django-crispy-forms==1.4.0
django-money==0.3.3
django-sortable-listview==0.23
easy-thumbnails==1.4
gevent==1.0
google-api-python-client==1.2
greenlet==0.4.1
gunicorn==18.0
httplib2==0.8
kombu==3.0.6
oauth2client==1.2
psycopg2==2.5.1
py==1.4.17
py-moneyed==0.4.1
pyadb==0.1.1
pyaml==13.07.1
pylibmc==1.2.3
pytest==2.4.2
python-dateutil==2.1
python-gflags==2.0
pytz==2013.8
reportlab==2.7
six==1.4.1
vobject==0.8.1c
wsgiref==:
```

0.1.2

`settings.py`

```
# Django settings for crm project.
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
# ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)
DOMAIN = '<MY_DOMAIN>'
MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '<DB_NAME>', # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '<DB_USER>',
        'PASSWORD': '<DB_PASS>',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1', 
        'PORT': '', 
    }
}

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*',] 

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Warsaw'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pl'

SITE_ID = 1
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT ='/var/www/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (

)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    #  'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '<NOT_THAT_STUPID>'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    #     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'crm.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'crm.wsgi.application'

import os
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'templates').replace('\\', '/'),)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'main',
    'crm',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django_localflavor_us',
    'django_localflavor_pl',
    'investApp',
    'addressbook',
    'sortable_listview',
    'djcelery',
    'gunicorn',
#    'south'
)

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt': "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },
    'file': {
        'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/home/<USER>/spcrm/debug.log',
    },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'investApp': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        }
    }
}
#memcache
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
#djcelery
BROKER_URL = "amqp://<USER>:<PASS>@localhost:5672/crm"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "database"
CELERY_RESULT_DBURI = "postgresql://<USER>:<PASS>@localhost/spcrm"

#crispy_forms theme
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap'

DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf-8'
DEFAULT_CURRENCY = 'PLN'

LOGIN_URL = 'LogMeIn'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'after_login'
# Converting warnings to errs to get line no NOT IN PRODUCTION!
# warnings.filterwarnings(
#         'error', r"DateTimeField received a naive datetime",
#         RuntimeWarning, r'django\.db\.models\.fields')


# put these two lines at the very bottom of the settings file
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

`/etc/init/celeryd.conf`:

```
description "celeryd"

start on (filesystem)
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn
console log
setuid <USER>
setgid nogroup
chdir /home/<USER>/spcrm

exec /home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/crm/bin/python /home/<USER>/spcrm/manage.py celeryd -B -E -loglevel=DEBUG
```

`/etc/init/gunicorn.conf`:

```
description "gunicorn"

start on (filesystem)
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn
console log 
setuid <USER>
setgid nogroup
chdir /home/<USER>/spcrm

#exec /home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/crm/bin/python /home/<USER>/spcrm/manage.py run_gunicorn -w 3 -k gevent --certfile=/home/<USER>/guni-cert.pem --keyfile=/home/<USER>uni-key.pem
exec /home/<USER>/.virtualenvs/crm/bin/python /home/<USER>/spcrm/manage.py run_gunicorn
```

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/spcrm`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    # If you want certain Non-SSL areas on your site, add a location block here
    # read up on the nginx docs.
    # Be sure to replace localhost in the following rule to the server name/IP address.
    return 301 https://subdomain.domain.com/;
}
server {
    listen  443 ssl;
    # server_name  _;
    # start mine
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /home/<USER>/guni-cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/<USER>/guni-key.pem;
    ssl_protocols        SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers          HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    server_name localhost;
    root /home/<USER>/spcrm/crm;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/spcrm.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/spcrm.error.log;

    location /static/{
        autoindex on;

        root /var/www/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10;
        proxy_read_timeout 10;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Comment: added `env HTTPS=on` to `gunicorn.conf` but still get `The page isn't redirecting properly` on every view that calls HttpResponseRedirect

Comment: Now I can login after deleting initial_data fixture And adding superuser on syncdb but redirect problem stand

Comment: found http://stackoverflow.com/a/8184225/1016772 but it would be great to avoid changing app code -it would be nightmare to mantain

Comment: Added `rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;` and removed `return 301 https://subdomain.domain.com/;` in first section of nginx conf - now it works ok i just must manually type https