# Django Admin page redirecting to the Home page with Gunicorn + Nginx when using SSL

Tags: python, django, ssl, nginx, gunicorn

My site is up and working, but I can't access the Django Admin page.  Every time I try to access `/admin/` it redirects me to the https home page.

I am using Gunicorn + Nginx for the first time, so I am pretty sure it has to do with the SSL settings, but am not sure how to configure it.

Here is my **Nginx config** file:

```
upstream app_server {
    server 104.131.57.229:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://mysite.com/;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;   
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www_mysite_com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.com.key;
    ssl_protocols        SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers          HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    server_name mysite.com;

    root /home/django/mysite_project/mysite/mysite;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/django/mysite_project/mysite/static/; 
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /home/django/mysite_project/mysite/templates;
    }
}
```

Here is my admin **urls.py**.  Pretty standard:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    # other urls
    )
```

I can access the Django Admin using my site url 9000 port, and this is normal `http`.  Maybe that is a security issue.  When I access the Admin this way however, there isn't an CSS styling, so it's hard to navigate.

I am running:

```
Ubuntu 14.04
Django 1.6.5
Python 3.4.0
Nginx 1.6.2
Gunicorn 19.1.1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AaronYsidoro have you set [SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#std:setting-SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER) for Django?

Comment: When you're getting the redirect are you accessing your website with http:// or https:// ? (It should only work with https:// in the above config)

Comment: @chuk2bp I added that setting to my `settings.py`, but it is still redirecting me to the home page, and not letting me access Django Admin.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @talyyweb I am accessing the website over `https`. But I still can't access the Django Admin over https.....

Comment: Can you access the admin if you do curl http:// 104.131.57.229:9000/admin from the server where your nginx is set up?

Comment: @talyyweb yes I can. But when I do, no CSS is rendered, so it's hard to navigate the Admin.  Does that help to solve what may be the issue?  Thanks

Comment: Ok, your problem seems to be described in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153875/how-to-deploy-an-https-only-site-with-django-nginx It goes into details how to solve it, but let me know if you still have issues after implementing this solution. Basically,  your problem is that django returns full urls to the browser with http:// which falls through your first server block to its return statement (which is your home page). This may also happen in other parts of your app.

Comment: @talyyweb thank you for your help on this.  It took me 2 days to look over the long question / answer that you linked, and find the solution, but yea the q/a u linked had the answer! I'm going to post the fix below. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was that in the `nginx config file`, I needed to change the `http` redirect config to redirect to the request URL in `https`, and not the `https home page`.

I first added this to my Django `settings.py` so Django trusts the https from the Nginx proxy:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

Next, I changed this original code which was redirecting from `http` to the `https home page` each time:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://mysite.com/;
}
```

To this new code which redirects to the requested URL, but the `https` of that URL:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    rewrite ^ https://mysite.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

And now Django will correctly (or Nginx rather), will correctly redirect to the requested URL.