# Setting up Https in Django 1.7+ with uwsgi and Nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, https

I'm having trouble setting up my site with https. At the moment, I have my nginx server set to listen to both http and https responses.

However, now I only want to allow https and redirect any http requests to htpps.

I tried this post without any luck: [How to deploy an HTTPS-only site, with Django/nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153875/how-to-deploy-an-https-only-site-with-django-nginx)

What is the recommended way of doing this in Django 1.7+?

Below is my ngninx.conf file:

```
# mysite_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///uwsgi-tutorial/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
#   server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen 80;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    #ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /uwsgi-tutorial/conf/www.example.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /uwsgi-tutorial/conf/www.example.com.key;

    # the domain name it will serve for
#   server_name localhost; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    server_name example.com; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /uwsgi-tutorial/mysite/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /uwsgi-tutorial/mysite/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /uwsgi-tutorial/mysite/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already a library that does this job just fine - sslify:

https://github.com/rdegges/django-sslify

Just proceed with instructions on github page.