# django_rest_swagger using http not https in "try it out" button

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, django-rest-swagger

I'm using Django Rest Framework with Django Rest Swagger for API documentation. It seems that the "try it out" button always submits http requests, not https requests, even though the browser is https.

I know how to do this if I rebuilt entire CoreAPI spec, but want to just pass something like protocol = 'https' to django_rest_swagger or something else that does not require re-coding the API documentation framework.

Answer (score 0):

are you behind a proxy?
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153875/how-to-deploy-an-https-only-site-with-django-nginx) worked for me. otherwise you can try specifying in your `wsgi.py` scheme='https' to force https on requests