# Facebook Final Check For Login

Tags: django, facebook-login, django-allauth

**I have created a django app where i am checking that my
 social login for facebook is workingor not. When i click on my Facebook Button from Frontend
 its not getting login i am facing security connection problem though i have used ngrok link
 for creating a secure tunnel but still i am unable to login .. i am using django-all-auth library**

settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["582b-2405-201-a006-70b4-35e2-8cb3-b7e2-b9ec.ngrok.io"]
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL= 'dashboard'
```

settings for facebook login inside the installed apps

```
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter'
```

site_id

```
SITE_ID = 12
```

urls.py for django-all-auth

```
path('socialaccounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

register.html

```
{% load socialaccount %}
{% providers_media_js %}
    
<a href="{% provider_login_url 'facebook' method='oauth2' %}" class="btn btn-primary form-btn w-100 mt-3">Facebook</a>`r code here
```

images

[This is the error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJaWG.png%22) 
[Provided a Valid OAuth Redirect URIs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubfnH.png%22)

[Basic settings for app inside facebook developers page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sau4Y.png%22)

Comment: Are you accessing your site over http? The redirect_uri in the facebook link is http

Comment: @IainShelvington i have given https link in the ValidOAuth Redirect URIs  .. i dnt understand why it is overriding as http have a look on the image for Valid OAuth i dnt understand where i am going wrong

Comment: That does not matter if you are accessing your site over http, the redirect_uri is generated from URL that you access your site with. Are you accessing your site  over http or https?

Comment: Your Django app does not think it is being served via https because it's behind a reverse proxy, you need to configure it. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65934202/548562

Comment: @IainShelvington what should i use http or https

Comment: https if that is what you configured in facebook's oauth settings

Comment: @IainShelvington should i change it to http

Comment: @IainShelvington i am using ngrok tunnel and it is giving us two link one is https and the other one is http which ngrok link should i use

Comment: Add those settings from the link above and then use https

Comment: @IainShelvington sorry i didnt get your point where i need  to add those settings from the link what should i add i didnt get your pont

Comment: I linked an answer above, configure `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST` and `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER` in your settings by following the linked aswer

Comment: ohh i need to add those seetings in my django app in settings.py then i can use https i mean if i will add validOauthurl which is related to https then i will not face any problem ,,

Comment: @IainShelvington thank you it solved my error .. can you just tell me whats the point of adding that one ... in the  seetings.py and in realtime can i use tose settings

Comment: When your site redirects you to facebook oauth it includes a redirect url which it generates from what it thinks the full URL of the app is. If you don't add those settings Django does not pick up that it is being served behind https and sends the wrong URL with http

Comment: using ngrok tunnel if i am creating a secure connection it is working can i login through localhost i tried it to login through localhost i am getting the same error.. but it is working if i am using ngrok link which starts with https

Comment: You won't be able to use oauth from localhost, the redirect_uri would never be valid

Comment: @IainShelvington which one is actually facebook console in facebook developers applicaton i need to add a ngrok link there for creating a safe tunnel by the way your answerr helped me a lot anyways pls tell me which one is  facebook console i am unable to recognise i need to past my ngrok link there .. is the valid Oauth redirect url is the console or what ..??